# I keep getting a syntax error, somehow due to the colon at the end of a function definition

Tags: python, syntax

I'm brand new to python, and programming in general, so this is probably something extremely simple, but I'm persistently getting this syntax error at the end of the line defining my function for minPayment.  I can't see any problem with it... here is the program so far.

## Problem set 1: credit card balance calculator

```
print 'Month 1'
OutstandingBalance = raw_input(float('enter your balance'))
AnnualInterestRate = raw_input(float('enter rate as a decimal(%/100)'))
MinimumMonthlyPaymentRate = raw_input(float('enter minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal(%/100)'))
def minPayment: 
     minPayment = MinimumMonthlyPaymentRate * OutstandingBalance
        print 'minimum payment='minPayment
    return minPayment
def accIntrst:
    accIntrst = (AnnualInterestRate/12.0) * OutstandingBalance
        print 'accrued interest = 'accIntrst
    return accIntrst
def balPaid:
    balPaid = accIntrst - minPayment
        print 'balance paid = 'balPaid
    return balPaid
def remBal:
    remBal = OutstandingBalance - balPaid
        print 'remaining balance = 'remBal
    return remBal
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the error you are getting, although it looks to me like your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Fixed it, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses to your functions. Python syntax dictates so.

So, instead of `def minPayment:`, write `def minPayment():` instead.

Comment: @ShamusChowenhill Keep your indentations aligned as well. And you're welcome. You might wanna hit the check mark next to this answer to signal that this question has already been answered.